# How do I make this JQuery code more efficient

Tags: jquery

(new to JQuery) I have a list of around 20 or so elements that need to be disabled when the page loads. The list of elements contains the full range of HTML <input> elements, each having distinct IDs that follow a general naming convention.

```
        $('#rmX\\.val').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#rmX\\.unit').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#rmX\\.ba').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#rmX\\.sms\\.opt').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#rmX\\.sms\\.val').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#rmX\\.sms\\.car').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#rmX\\.em\\.opt').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#rmX\\.em\\.val').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#rmX\\.off\\.opt1').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#rmX\\.off\\.opt2').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#rmX\\.off\\.val').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#rmZ\\.end\\.vald').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#rmZ\\.end\\.valw').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#rmZ\\.end\\.valm').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#rmZ\\.end\\.valy').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#rmZ\\.date').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#rmZ\\.time').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#rmZ\\.ap').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#evt\\.sec\\.opt2').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#evt\\.sec\\.val21').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#evt\\.sec\\.val22').prop("disabled",true);
```

Is there a way to make this list more efficient or is this just the way ya'll do it.

(PS. surprised there isn't a "best-practices" tag available.)

EDIT: Changed "hidden" from original question to "disabled" as is displayed in my code.

Comment: Why don't you use an extra class on all those elements that need to be disabled an just do `$('.yourClass').prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: Oh, you have a dot in your ID value. How convenient, isn't it? `:P`

Comment: There's no "best-practices" tag because there's a [whole forum dedicated to code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks Sparky. The Internet is a big place. Didn't even know this existed. I'll use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not add a class `canBeDisabled` to all the elements in your `#evt` that you want to disable?

```
$("#evt .canBeDisabled").prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: I'll add that elements can have more than one class. You'll be surprised by how many people don't know this.

Comment: Jon, that was going to be my next question. I'll look it up. Thanks. Erik, many thanks. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @JonP I guess it's not inherently obvious because its name isn't `classes=""`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class and then do this way:

```
$('.hideClass').hide();
```

(Or)

```
$("#rmX\\.val, #rmX\\.unit, #rmX\\.ba, #rmX\\.ba").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store those strings inside an array:

```
var arr = [ '#rmX\\.val', '#rmX\\.unit', ... ];
```

and then:

```
$.each( arr, function ( i, val ) {
    $( val ).prop( 'disabled', true );
});
```

This won't make it more efficient, but it removes the code repetition.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach is if the fields are grouped together you could use a parent object such as a div or better still a field set.

For a quick and dirty example see [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/BpC6w/1/)